# UPDATEXML when there is namespaces

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-namespaces, updatexml

I have to update value in XML:

```
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
                  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
                  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
                  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
                  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
            <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
                <Author>XXXXXX</Author>
                <LastAuthor>UCB User</LastAuthor>
                <Created>2019-10-31T13:04:09Z</Created>
                <Version>14.00</Version>
            </DocumentProperties>
            <a>5</a>
        </Workbook>
```

In my case this XML is in table **tt** field **xml_val**.

Goal XPath is **/Workbook/DocumentProperties/Created** with value *2019-10-31T13:04:09Z* and have to be replaced with *2020-01-08*.

I tied this code:

```
select UPDATEXML(xml_val,
   '/Workbook/DocumentProperties/Created/text()','2020-01-08',
    'xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
              xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
              xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
              xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
              xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"').getClobVal() as last
from tt;
```

//.getClobVal() in the end is because *ORA-21500: internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]* ([here](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=58463))

Code above doesn't change anything. I thing this is because there is another namespace declared in **DocumentProperties** tag. But I don't know how to declare namespaces in [UPDATEXML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions205.htm) clause.

When I tried to update value in **/Workbook/a** with this code, it works corect:

```
select UPDATEXML(xml_val,
   '/Workbook/a/text()',2020-01-08,
    'xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
              xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
              xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
              xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
              xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"').getClobVal() as last
from tt;
```

Different namespace combination that I tried and not works:

--1

```
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
```

--2

```
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
```

--3

```
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
```

--4

```
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
```

NOTE: I can't remove the namespace declaration in DocumentProperties tag because this XML is part from [Excel-XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) format file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DocumentProperties` element and its children are in the namespace `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office` which has the shortcut `o`; you need to prefix those elements with their namespace in the Xpath:

```sql
SELECT UPDATEXML(
         xml_val,
         '/Workbook/o:DocumentProperties/o:Created/text()',
         '2020-01-08',
         'xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
          xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
          xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
          xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
          xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"'
       ) AS updated_xml
FROM   tt;
```

> ```
> | UPDATED_XML                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>XXXXXX</Author><LastAuthor>UCB User</LastAuthor><Created>2020-01-08</Created><Version>14.00</Version></DocumentProperties><a>5</a></Workbook> |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4ae5c6f099a4111a9beebf98d94d50d8)*

However, `UPDATEXML` is deprecated and you should use `XMLQUERY`:

```sql
SELECT XMLQuery(
         'declare default element namespace "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"; (: :)
          declare namespace o = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"; (: :)
          copy $i := $x modify 
          ( for $j in $i/Workbook/o:DocumentProperties/o:Created
            return replace value of node $j with $v )
          return $i'
         PASSING xml_val AS "x",
                 '2020-01-08' AS "v"
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ) AS updated_xml
FROM   tt
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=df2c5b121a9f42de0a7bd11dcc1578d0)*