# Oracle XML Update troubles

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a BPMN2.0 XML value stored in a CLOB in a table.

it has structure similar to this

```
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="Definitions_17dxovu" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="bpmn-js (https://demo.bpmn.io)" exporterVersion="4.0.3">
  <bpmn:collaboration id="Collaboration_1wfeho3">
    <bpmn:participant id="Participant_0fn1t3b" name="Participant" processRef="Process_16me3ie" />
  </bpmn:collaboration>
  <bpmn:process id="Process_16me3ie">
    <bpmn:dataStoreReference id="DataStoreReference_16vk15q" name="Entity Data Repository" />
    <bpmn:startEvent id="Event_0ncce8e">
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_16gz7yv</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:task id="Activity_12og88i" name="oldval">
    </bpmn:task>
```

etc.

I desire to simply update the name attribute of the task with a new name.

so I attempted various flavors of this:

```
UPDATE process p
SET p.bpmn_xml = updatexml( p.bpmn_xml, '//bpmn:task[@id="Activity_12og88i" ]/name[text()="oldval"]/text()', 'newval' );
```

but I get many errors including this

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got - at line xxx
```

pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four issues:

1. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646927/1509264), you need to include the namespaces in the 4th argument to `UPDATEXML`;
2. `UPDATEXML` takes an `XMLTYPE` as the first parameter so you need to convert your `CLOB` to and from that;
3. You want to use the XPath `//bpmn:task[@id="Activity_12og88i" and @name="oldval"]/@name`; and
4. Your XML is invalid as it is missing closing tags.

Like this:

```
UPDATE process
SET bpmn_xml = updatexml(
                 XMLTYPE(bpmn_xml),
                 '//bpmn:task[@id="Activity_12og88i" and @name="oldval"]/@name',
                 'newval',
                 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"
                  xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI"
                  xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC"
                  xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"'
               ).getClobVal();
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE process (bpmn_xml CLOB );

INSERT INTO process (bpmn_xml)
VALUES ('<bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="Definitions_17dxovu" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="bpmn-js (https://demo.bpmn.io)" exporterVersion="4.0.3">
  <bpmn:collaboration id="Collaboration_1wfeho3">
    <bpmn:participant id="Participant_0fn1t3b" name="Participant" processRef="Process_16me3ie" />
  </bpmn:collaboration>
  <bpmn:process id="Process_16me3ie">
    <bpmn:dataStoreReference id="DataStoreReference_16vk15q" name="Entity Data Repository" />
    <bpmn:startEvent id="Event_0ncce8e">
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_16gz7yv</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:task id="Activity_12og88i" name="oldval">
    </bpmn:task>   
  </bpmn:process>
</bpmn:definitions>');
```

Updates the XML to:

| BPMN_XML |
| --- |
| <bpmn:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="Definitions_17dxovu" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="bpmn-js (https://demo.bpmn.io)" exporterVersion="4.0.3"><bpmn:collaboration id="Collaboration_1wfeho3"><bpmn:participant id="Participant_0fn1t3b" name="Participant" processRef="Process_16me3ie"/></bpmn:collaboration><bpmn:process id="Process_16me3ie"><bpmn:dataStoreReference id="DataStoreReference_16vk15q" name="Entity Data Repository"/><bpmn:startEvent id="Event_0ncce8e"><bpmn:outgoing>Flow_16gz7yv</bpmn:outgoing></bpmn:startEvent><bpmn:task id="Activity_12og88i" name="newval"> </bpmn:task></bpmn:process></bpmn:definitions> |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kdoA8OJl)